# Select single checkbox using checkBoxListTile - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Am trying to select one or more check boxes from a list of check boxes, i have found that the best option is using the `checkBoxListTile` widget to implement this.

First i have defined a list and used the widget as follows:

```
List<String> _texts = ["google.com", "youtube.com", "yahoo.com", "gmail.com"];

      Expanded(
        child: ListView(
          children: _texts
              .map((text) => CheckboxListTile(
                    title: Text(text),
                    value: _isChecked,
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      setState(() {
                        _isChecked = val;
                      });
                    },
                  ))
              .toList(),
        ),
      ),
```

check boxes are displayed fine but whenever i click one checkbox all are checked, how can i handle choosing one or more check boxes from the list?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code hope its help to you I have try it other way

#### Only Single Checkbox Selected:

Your List :

```
List _texts = [
    {
      "value": false,
      "site": "google.com",
    },
    {
      "value": false,
      "site": "youtube.com",
    },
    {
      "value": false,
      "site": "yahoo.com",
    },
    {
      "value": false,
      "site": "gmail.com",
    },
  ];
```

Your Widget:

```
Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0, vertical: 64.0),
        child: Column(
          children: List.generate(
            _texts.length,
            (index) => CheckboxListTile(
              controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              dense: true,
              title: Text(
                _texts[index]["site"],
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16.0,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
              value: _texts[index]["value"],
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  for (var element in _texts) {
                    element["value"] = false;
                  }
                  _texts[index]["value"] = value;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

#### Full Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Flutter Single Checkbox Example"),
          ),
          body: SafeArea(
              child: Center(
            child: CheckboxWidget(),
          ))),
    );
  }
}

class CheckboxWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  CheckboxWidgetState createState() => new CheckboxWidgetState();
}

class CheckboxWidgetState extends State {
  List _texts = [
    {
      "value": false,
      "site": "google.com",
    },
    {
      "value": false,
      "site": "youtube.com",
    },
    {
      "value": false,
      "site": "yahoo.com",
    },
    {
      "value": false,
      "site": "gmail.com",
    },
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0, vertical: 64.0),
      child: Column(
        children: List.generate(
          _texts.length,
          (index) => CheckboxListTile(
            controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            dense: true,
            title: Text(
              _texts[index]["site"],
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16.0,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
            value: _texts[index]["value"],
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                for (var element in _texts) {
                  element["value"] = false;
                }
                _texts[index]["value"] = value;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Result Screen-> [image]

#### Multiple Checkbox Selection

**Your List/Map**

```
  Map<String, bool> values = {
    'google.com': false,
    'youtube.com': false,
    'yahoo.com': false,
    'gmail.com': false,
  };
```

Your Function:

```
  var tmpArray = [];  
  getCheckboxItems() {
    values.forEach((key, value) {
      if (value == true) {
        tmpArray.add(key);
      }
    });

    print(tmpArray);
    tmpArray.clear();
  }
```

Your Widget:

```
Column(
      children: <Widget>[
          ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: values.keys.map((String key) {
              return new CheckboxListTile(
                title: new Text(key),
                value: values[key],
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    values[key] = value!;
                  });
                },
              );
            }).toList(),
          
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 100,
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          child: Text(
            " Checkbox Items ",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
          ),
          onPressed: getCheckboxItems,
        ),
      ],
    )
```

#### Full Example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Flutter Multiple Checkbox Example"),
          ),
          body: SafeArea(
              child: Center(
            child: CheckboxWidget(),
          ))),
    );
  }
}

class CheckboxWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  CheckboxWidgetState createState() => new CheckboxWidgetState();
}

class CheckboxWidgetState extends State {
  Map<String, bool> values = {
    'google.com': false,
    'youtube.com': false,
    'yahoo.com': false,
    'gmail.com': false,
  };

  var tmpArray = [];

  getCheckboxItems() {
    values.forEach((key, value) {
      if (value == true) {
        tmpArray.add(key);
      }
    });

    print(tmpArray);
    tmpArray.clear();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
          ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: values.keys.map((String key) {
              return new CheckboxListTile(
                title: new Text(key),
                value: values[key],
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    values[key] = value!;
                  });
                },
              );
            }).toList(),
          
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 100,
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          child: Text(
            " Checkbox Items ",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
          ),
          onPressed: getCheckboxItems,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Result Screen-> [image]

Refer Video Tutorial for ***Flutter Multiselect Dropdown Checkbox*** on [**YouTube**](https://youtu.be/Ldg_TO988no)

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer that solved my problem and gave new idea, but can i ask what is the elevated button job here? does it print the check box values ?

Comment: @editix Yes, Elevated Button Print the selected checkbox value from list

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

/// This Widget is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: _title,
      home: CheckBoxExample(),
    );
  }
}

class CheckBoxExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const CheckBoxExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CheckBoxExample> createState() => _CheckBoxExampleState();
}

class _CheckBoxExampleState extends State<CheckBoxExample> {
  String selectedMonth = "";
  List checkListItems = [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "value": false,
      "monthName": "January",
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "value": false,
      "monthName": "Febuary",
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "value": false,
      "monthName": "March",
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "value": false,
      "monthName": "April",
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "value": false,
      "monthName": "May",
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "value": false,
      "monthName": "June",
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "value": false,
      "monthName": "July",
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "value": false,
      "monthName": "August",
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "value": false,
      "monthName": "September",
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "value": false,
      "monthName": "October",
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "value": false,
      "monthName": "November",
    },
    {
      "id": 11,
      "value": false,
      "monthName": "December",
    },
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0, vertical: 64.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              selectedMonth,
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 85.0),
            Column(
              children: List.generate(
                checkListItems.length,
                (index) => CheckboxListTile(
                  controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  dense: true,
                  title: Text(
                    checkListItems[index]["monthName"],
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                  value: checkListItems[index]["value"],
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      for (var element in checkListItems) {
                        element["value"] = false;
                      }
                      checkListItems[index]["value"] = value;
                      selectedMonth ="${checkListItems[index]["id"]+1}, ${checkListItems[index]["monthName"]}";
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),          
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `value` parameter for in `CheckboxListTile` is how widget knows whether checkbox is checked or not. When you give all of them same `value`, all of their state changes.
You can keep a seperate list to keep track of if the specific checkbox is checked.

Comment: do you mean whenever i check or unchecked a box i add or remove its value within another list ?, if you can elaborate more using a code ill be thankful

Comment: I meant keeping a list of bool for each one of your checklist, setting false initially and updating current state in onChecked method but seems like answers with code have already posted