# Select one option only using Multi Select Dialog Field Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using the MultiSelectDialogField widget, but I wanted the user to be able to select only one option, does anyone know if there's a way to do this with this widget?
Or if there is another widget with dialog that is more recommended?

```dart
 MultiSelectDialogField(
            searchable: true,
            items: _itensStudent,
            title: const Text("Students"),
            selectedColor: Colors.black,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(
                color: theme.primaryColor,
                width: 2,
              ),
            ),
            isDismissible: false,
            buttonText: Text(
              "Select student",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: theme.primaryColor,
                fontSize: 16,
              ),
            ),
            chipDisplay: MultiSelectChipDisplay.none(),
            onConfirm: (results) {
            },
          ),
```

[image]

Comment: Try to refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74889012/13997210) hope its help to you

Comment: Use radio buttons if you want to select just one option. Here the widget ---> https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Radio-class.html

Comment: both options solve my problem thanks guys