# changing state of a dynamic checkbox

Tags: flutter, dart

i have code that helps me dynamically create checkbox buttons from data in my api , now I need a way to help change the state of the check box values when i tap or untap them ,how can go about doing this -

```
                           for (int i = 0; i < data.names.length;i++)  
                          CheckboxListTile(
                              title: Text(data.names[i]),
                              value: false,
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                
                              })
```

Comment: Refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74889012/13997210) for checkbox using list

Answer (score 0):

Just use a variable and update it every time to change the checkbox.

```
bool checkBoxSelected = false;
```

In your onChange you set it to the current value and update your ui.

```
setState((){
checkBoxSelected = value;
});
```

And set the current value of your checkbox to the variable (so it isn't false every time):

```
value: checkBoxSelected,
```

Comment: this as a result changes the state of every checkbox as opposed to selected one

Comment: Okay, if you have a List of checkbox you will also need a List of booleans. I would put it the boolean in your data value, so you can easily get the value for the checkbox with value : data[index].value

Comment: could you please provide an example , im not understanding ?

Answer (score 0):

i have create demo code as per your requirement ant try this demo:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CheckBoxScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const CheckBoxScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<CheckBoxScreen> createState() => _CheckBoxScreenState();
}

class _CheckBoxScreenState extends State<CheckBoxScreen> {
  List<bool> checkboxValues = [];
  Map<String, bool> checkboxMap = {};

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    for (int i = 0; i < data.names.length; i++) {
      String name = data.names[i];
      checkboxValues.add(false);
      checkboxMap[name] = false;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Checkbox App'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data.names.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return CheckboxListTile(
            title: Text(data.names[index]),
            value: checkboxValues[index],
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                checkboxValues[index] = value ?? false;
                checkboxMap[data.names[index]] = value ?? false;
              });
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DataModel {
  List<String> names;
  DataModel({required this.names});
}

DataModel data = DataModel(
  names: [
    'Name 1',
    'Name 2',
    'Name 3',
    'Name 4',
    'Name 5',
  ],
);
```

Comment: im making an api call hence "data" thus for loop would need to occur after the build

Answer (score 0):

Detailed example for your reference. Hope it helps.

```
class _CustomCheckboxState extends State<CustomCheckbox> {  List<Map<String, dynamic>> checkListItems = [
{
  "id": 1,
  "value": false,
  "title": "Reason1",
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "value": false,
  "title": "Reason2",
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "value": false,
  "title": "Reason3",
},
{
  "id": 4,
  "value": false,
  "title": "Reason4",
} ];

@override 
Scaffold build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text("App Bar"),
    ),
    body: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: checkListItems.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => CheckboxListTile(
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
        controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
        title: Text(
          "${checkListItems[index]["title"]}",
        ),
        value: checkListItems[index]["value"],
        checkboxShape:
            RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
        onChanged: (value) =>
            setState(() => checkListItems[index]["value"] = value),
      ),
    ),
  );}
```